# Finger Millet ( a.k.a Ragi millet ) for house sparrow

Tags: ornithology

I have a sparrow feeder at home, and im wondering whether Finger Millets are good for the little sparrow's tummy .. ? Looking for advice , thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, but several things come immediately to mind.   First, as you know, small birds like to eat millet, which must seem like fast-food to them.   However, sparrows are ordinarily urban creatures these days, and while they might have forgotten how nice millet is to eat, they'll probably enjoy it too, in sensible quantities.   You might even want to experiment with various seeds to determine just how much; bearing in mind that just because a creature loves a particular food does not mean that it is not also harmful to them.   (Consider the case of sunflower seeds and cancer in white cockatoos; and pizzas in humans).

It's hard to imagine a creature as tough and versatile as a sparrow having any difficulty with such food though.  Don't worry.